# Color picker dialog in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Using

```
<input type="color">
```

it is possible to call the system's color picker dialog. That works just fine, but I'd like to use different button for this. Is it possible to manually call the color picker dialog from another element?

Comment: Just assign Id to it and change it using css. Here is one example http://jsfiddle.net/dt53pguq/

Comment: There's still going to be the outer rectangle though.

Comment: The color rectangle is the main functionality of this control. I don't think you can override it, as HTML tag has the most priority.

Comment: you can hide the color input and use a custom element (any div, button etc) to trigger the click event via javascript on the hidden input element. This way you can style your button as you like.

Comment: And how can I do that, ynnus?

Comment: Stack Overflow has answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define its style, for example remove the border, with the style property:

```
<input type="color" style="border:none">
```

Comment: That still won't remove the grey rectangle. http://s29.postimg.org/68zqako1v/Untitled.png

Comment: The "grey rectangle" ist the background color which can be defined by css to any other color, or even none.

Comment: I know it's color can be changed, but I'd like to remove it (if possible). Thanks for your anwser, though.

Comment: add "background-color:#fff; padding:0;" to the style